# Why toLowerCase() gives type error in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to check a email subject against a keyword, and trying do an indexOf. It works without toLowerCase()

```
if(subj.toLowerCase().indexOf(range1.getValues().toLowerCase()) != -1 && !range1.isBlank())
```

With toLowerCase() it gives a TypeError

```
TypeError: The toLowerCase function can not be opened in a VALUE object.
```

Comment: In this comment, it supposes that ``range1`` is an object of Range. When it's so, the reason of the error is that the values retrieved by ``getValues()`` is an array. In your case, it is 2 dimensional array. Although I'm not sure whether ``subj`` is a string value, the error occurs by this. And also, when ``range1`` is an object of Range, ``!range1.isBlank()`` is always ``true``. If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`range1.getValues()` always returns a 2D array. Even if `range1` is one cell, in which case it returns `[[something]]`.

Use `range1.getValue()` to get the value `something` directly.

Comment: not really tested your comment, hopefully it's legit, but I solved it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer might be correct, but I solved it this way actually:

```
range1.getValues().toString().toLowerCase()
```